# CXF Custom Validation Interceptor with custom response not working

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am trying to write a Custom CXF Interceptor to do some validations on SOAP request to a web service. Based on the validation results, I want to block the request to web service and return the response with some modified parameters.

For this, I have written custom CXF ininterceptor extending from AbstractPhaseInterceptor, to run in phase USER_LOGICAL, which does validations, but I am not able to stop the subsequent call to web service and also not able to pass the Custom Response object(Custom Response object type is same as web service return type). How can I do this using interceptors?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research upon the tip from nadirsaghar and I found it to be the cleanes solution available. Using message.getExchange() in JAX-WS is a complete pain, since you have to setup a conduit and fill the response message yourself...

So better do it this way, using HttpServletResponse. - You need to have the java servlet-api.jar on your Path. If you're developing without maven, just link it from your webserver (e.g. tomcat) directory, but exlude it from deployment.

```
<!-- With Maven add the following dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <!-- The version should match your WebService version e.g. 3.0 for JDK7-->
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

With scope provided it will not be deployed and is just available so you can access the HttpServletResponse class.

Your Handler Code:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage( final Message message ) throws Fault
{
    if( shouldBlockMessage( message ) )
    {
        message.getInterceptorChain().abort();

        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)message.get( AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_RESPONSE );

        // To redirect a user to a different Page
        response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY );
        response.setHeader( "Location", "http://www.bla.blubb/redirectPage" );

        // Other possibility if a User provides faulty login data
        response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can abort execution of the interceptorChain including the webservice using `abort` method

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) {

    InterceptorChain chain = message.getInterceptorChain();
    chain.abort();
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it stops the interceptor chain completely without returning a response. Is there a way to pass the custom response after stopping the interceptor chain?

Comment: @Sumit : I think you can directly manipulate the HttpServletResponse by getting a reference from `message.get(AbstractHttpDestination.HTTP_RESPONSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, there is no need to play with Interceptor chain.

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
   //your logic
   Response response = Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
   message.getExchange().put(Response.class, response);

}
```

Comment: I just checked Response object belong to RestFul web services package. Will it also work with SOAP service?

Comment: oh i missed that part .. haven't worked with SOAP so i can only guess that there must be an analogy for Response in SOAP framework also and you will have to find out.